# Invalid host header using gitpod

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, gitpod

running a ionic angular code using gitpod.io is shows compile successfully message in terminal but the browser shows Invalid host header, error how to resolve this?

I'm trying to resolve this error any one can help with correct answer

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share your repository link.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --disable-host-check true", update npm start command in package.json accordingly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --disable-host-check true , this worked for me Thank you